# Can we use "in" + "today"?

Tags: grammar

I was writing a text to a friend and my sentence was "sorry to disturb you for the second time in today". Is this sentence right, or should I go with "sorry to disturb you for the second time today"?

Comment: *Today* already means "**on** this day". So by saying *in today*, you're saying "**in on** this day". Which, of course, is rubbish.

Comment: Hello, Akshit. Our sister site, ELL, is aimed at those learning English at a more basic level. 'In today' is far from being **right**. //  "Sorry to disturb you for the second time today" is fine grammatically, but 90% of native speakers would probably go with "Sorry to disturb you again".

Comment: I can imagine a number of situations where you might want to show that you realize you're disturbing someone for the second time in one day. Your second sentence is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: It's a case of volume.  The prepositions mark the metaphoric "shape"; bigger is more, as usual. Days are flat (_**on** this day_); smaller time units are points on a line or plane (_**at** this moment_), and larger units are containers (_**in** the next month_).